# UIView subview's elements not accessible

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a plain UIViewController class. At the top of the view, I have a subview that is set to a custom class called HeaderView. I am trying to use an XIB to define the elements of that custom view and loading it in as the controller loads as follows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var headerView: HeaderView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let view = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("HeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? HeaderView {
        self.headerView.addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

This **seems** to work as the view as described in the XIB is visible when the main view is shown. However when I try to access the elements inside the subview, the app crashes.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    headerView.headerLabel.text = "Success!"   // Crash here
}
```

Example project here: https://github.com/AaronBratcher/ViewTester

This technique works when specifying the header view of a section in a UITableView.

What am I missing?

Comment: If the thing you're loading is a HeaderView, making it a subview of your HeaderView property doesn't seem right.

Comment: I think the crash is not an automatic one, you need to actually stop the program in Xcode, right?

Comment: Download and run the sample project referred to. It crashes. It's not stopping on a breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

```
if let view = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("HeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? HeaderView {
    self.headerView.addSubview(view)
}
```

In this piece of code, you are adding a subview to a nil `HeaderView` property. This is not correct. You need to instantiate `HeaderView` object and assign it to you property, this way:

```
self.headerView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("HeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? HeaderView
```

Comment: Actually that's not true. self.headerView is set on the loading of the view because of the storyboard link. If you download the sample project I refer to and put a breakpoint on the addSubview line, you're see that self.headerView is not nil.